# Pest identification

Tags: identification, houseplants, indoors, pests, insects

I'm dealing with an infestation in many of my plants, and it seems to be different things. Generally my plants are very happy, but every once in a while one of them just rapidly detoriates, with yellowing -> browning and plant death soon following. Last time I figured it was rot due to excessive watering, but with the problem returning.. and the fact I can actually see some sort of mites - I want to fight this.

It's definitely spread to almost all of my plants, which I don't understand. Do these things fly? Anyway, here is plant A:

[image]

It's suffering and losing leaves. 2/3 of these plants are having this issue. Here's a closeup of the stem to the right:
[image]

Here's a dead leaf with something going on, as well:

[image]

Those seem to be larvae? And what are the red spots? Bonus points for identifying this plant btw, I don't know what it is called.

Regardless, as soon as I saw the pest I showered all of my plants and scrubbed every leaf with soap. Recurring sights on plants get an additional shower a day. **But they keep coming back, so I would like to understand precisely what this is and what a targeted approach could be.**

I've started mixing insect soap and selectively treating some plants, but considering whether I should unleash some sort of predator at this point.

I should add I've spotted this guy on another plant as well (just the one):
[image]

And one other plant (*Monstera*) with mites also developed some sort of red scarring / webbing on the underside...

[image]

Thank you so much for any pointers / ideas, having all my plants slowly die would be heart breaking.

Comment: Good question and good illustrations; if could include an overall illustration & closer illustration of the tops & leaves, illustration & known names of the plants, length of insects, length of larvae, how long insects have been there, type of soap solution used, hours of direct sunlight & of diffused light, average daytime & night time temperature, current watering regimen, current nutrient type & regimen, containers, and soil, could also be helpful. We encourage you to take the [Tour], and browse through the [Help], to learn more about how the site works! Thank you! Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 3):

Top insects are thrips: https://www.rhs.org.uk/advice/profile?pid=876 and will be causing some damage, other insect is a psocid https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psocoptera and should not be a problem for the plant.